# Clicking on a link to call an ActionResult with parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an Actionlink that should be clickable. It should pass the invoice number
to a method called Report in my controller. I created a route for this and it is shown
below. 
At the moment I am not able to hit the Report method with the parameter passed. Nothing
happens. My page just flicker. 
What am I missing?

```
             @foreach (var objUser in Model.Invoices)
             {
                    <tr>            
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="ckCheck" /></td>
                        <td>@objUser.invoiceDate</td>                 
                        <td>@Html.ActionLink(objUser.invoiceNumber, "Report", new { id = objUser.invoiceNumber }) </td>
                        <td>@objUser.accountNumber</td>
                        <td>@String.Format("{0:#,0.00}", objUser.amount)</td>
                        <td>@String.Format("{0:#,0.00}", objUser.amountDue)</td>
                    </tr>
             }


              public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
                    {
                        var routeProvider = PluginLocator.GetPlugin<IRouteProvider>();
                        routes.MapRoute(null, "Invoice", new { controller = "Invoice", action = "Report" });
                        routeProvider.RegisterRoutes(routes); 
                    }


              public ActionResult Report(int id = 0)
                    {           
                        ReportClass rptH = new ReportClass();
                        rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("/myreport/ourReport.rpt");
                        rptH.Load();
                        rptH.SetDatabaseLogon("zombie", "zombie29");
                        rptH.SetParameterValue("PARAM_REPORT_RUN_ID", id);
                        Stream stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
                        return File(stream, "application/pdf");
                    }
```

Comment: Is there some javascript on your page that might be hijacking the click on the link? Also what do you see in the Net tab of FireBug? Is an AJAX request or a normal request being sent to the server when the link is clicked? What's the generated `href` on the link?

Comment: This is all I get http://dev.site/invoice?id=103456723  I don't see the Report method as part of the url though.

Comment: Yeah that seems wrong. Looks like you have problems with your route definitions. Hard to say without knowing how you declared all your routes.

Comment: This is how I declared my route. routes.MapRoute(null, "Invoice", new { controller = "Invoice", action = "Report" });

Comment: No, you seem to be using some custom `PluginLocator.GetPlugin<IRouteProvider>()` method which is absolutely unclear what it is doing nor where it is coming from. Maybe it registers some other routes which we cannot know about from your question. Without showing your real code or at least some code snippet in which you have narrowed down the problem it will be pretty though to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me.

```
 routes.MapRoute(null, "Invoice/{action}", new { controller = "Invoice", 
                                                            action = "Index" });
```

Introducing "`Invoice/{action}"` made it work.